# How to override styles between parent - child elements using css selector?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

hei!
I am trying to modify navigation menus in wordpress and here's the html part of the navigation menus:

```
<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="menu-toggle">Primary Menu</h1>
    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
    <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="nav-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-25" class="recipes menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a href="">Recipes</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-26" class="wine menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-26"><a href="">Wine</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-27" class="cocktails menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27"><a href="">Cocktails</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and here's the css part that controls the background color of the menu items on hover:

```
.primary-navigation li:hover > a,
.primary-navigation li.focus > a {
        background-color: #24890d;
        color: #fff;
}
```

I want each menu item to have their individual background color on hover and tried following css but it didn't work:

```
.primary-navigation .recipes li:hover > a,
.primary-navigation .recipes li.focus > a {
        background-color: #e5ebd5;
        color: #fff;
}

.primary-navigation .wine li:hover > a,
.primary-navigation .wine li.focus > a {
        background-color: #8d89a1;
        color: #fff;
}

.primary-navigation .cocktails li:hover > a,
.primary-navigation .cocktails li.focus > a {
        background-color: #85b0ad;
        color: #fff;
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here and what will be the right way to do it?

PS: Do I also have to remove the original css part which is currently controlling the background color on hover for all menu items or there is a way to override it?

Thanks and regards,

Shyam Singh

Comment: Have you tried !important ? background-color: #85b0ad !important; color: #fff !important; etc etc

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but that didn't work too.

Comment: try, as selector : .primary-navigation li.recipes:hover , in this way, you are selective li elements that have a recipes class. Currently you are selecting li elements that are in a recipes class

Comment: It worked like a charm, I've marked your post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my previous comment, this is how the selectors should be :

```
.primary-navigation  li.recipes:hover > a,
.primary-navigation  li.recipes:focus > a {
        background-color: #e5ebd5;
        color: #fff;
}

.primary-navigation  li.wine:hover > a,
.primary-navigation  li.wine:focus > a {
        background-color: #8d89a1;
        color: #fff;
}

.primary-navigation  li.cocktails:hover > a,
.primary-navigation  li.cocktails:focus > a {
        background-color: #85b0ad;
        color: #fff;
}
```

In this way, you are selective li elements that have a recipes class. Currently you are selecting li elements that are in a recipes class

**EDIT based on BoltClock response**
also keep in mind that focus is a pseudo-class, not a class ( for a pseudo-class, you are using ":" not "." )

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/34LGg/)

Comment: It's called a pseudo-class - properties are entirely different from selectors (although they both happen to use colons).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.primary-navigation .recipes li:hover > a
.primary-navigation .wine li:hover > a
.primary-navigation .cocktails li:hover > a
```

with this (and same for :focus)

```
.primary-navigation .recipes:hover > a
.primary-navigation .wine:hover > a
.primary-navigation .cocktails:hover > a
```

Because you trying to search li element inside this li element.